# Which mathematical properties do PSNR and MSE hold?

Tags: metric, mean-squared-error, image-super-resolution, ssim, psnr

We know the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) holds the following properties:

- Unique maximum:  `S(x, y) = 1 if and only if x = y`
- Boundedness:  `S(x, y) ≤ 1`
- Symmetry:  `S(x, y) = S(y, x)`

My question is: **do we know simple some properties like these for Peak signal-to-noise ratio (PSNR)? And for MSE?** Do some of the above properties hold for PSNR and MSE? For instance, I have never obtained a PSNR value higher than 80 and, in microscopy super-resolution, never higher than 30.

PS: Do you know any other interesting property of any metric?

Comment: It would be great if you split this post into 2, one for each metric, so that people can focus on one metric at time. Can you please do that?

Comment: Of course! Do you mean one for properties of PSNR and another one for properties of MSE? I put them together because PSNR is highly determined by MSE. Thanks!